# Rails Form Builder with list of images to select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to create a rails form builder in active admin, one of input tag as drop down with list of images for selection, instead of default select tag with some text data. I guess we should try playing with overriding form builders, i would like to know if someone has come across facing this situation and found out some solution.

Comment: something like [this](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/)?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to implement in similar way.. Having trouble setting custom attributes for select options in rails active admin form builder.